# Database Structure for Tracking and Analysing Products

Tags: sql, database, statistics, analytics, database-schema

I’m building a tool to track products from an external supplier – I get a daily feed via an API of the products they have listed (ID, name, price, category) etc. and I want to do various bits of analysis on this such as calculating average price per category, average product listing time etc. to identify some trends.

I’m not sure what the best way to store this data – at the moment, I have a table as follows:

- ID (Primary Key)
- Name
- Price
- Category
- Etc
- Date First Seen
- Date Last Seen

I take a daily feed form the supplier, do an Insert or Update on Duplicate – If a product has already been added to the table, then it updates the Date Last Seen column with today’s date. If a product is not in the daily api feed, it means it is no longer listed and therefore the Date Last Seen would show a historical date.

With a few thousand products, this insert or update command is taking a minute or so; my full product set will be around 400k daily so I expect will take significantly longer (out of the 400k products, maybe 0.5% will be new entries so need to be added, 0.5% would have dropped off from the previous day so would not updated and the rest will be existing so the last seen date would need to be updated).

Is there any other more efficient approach that I can take with this?

Currently using ASP.NET and C-Sharp for the tool and database is MySQL, although open to MSSQL / other database server as well.

Comment: What happens if you for the same product get a change in price?  Do you then have two different records in the same table?  If so that can cause slowness.  Also database structure can contribute to slowness.  But the level of slowness you describe suggests that although the database design may not be optimized the level of slowness you describe is not likely cause by the structure.  You most likely don't have a needed index or have code related issues....

Comment: Also try to not interact with sql one row at a time.  Try to load with sql calls doing 100 or more rows at a time.  Looping through row by row can slowness.

Comment: On the price change, i have a seperate table that api feed that shows historical price changes so i was planning to put that in another table and do some joins.

Comment: On not interacting one row at a time - what would be the way to insert 100 etc rows at a time? at the moment, my code generates an SQL script which i then run - ** insert into table values .... on duplicate key update date_last_seen **

Comment: If you make a sql statement with 100 inserts and ran them as a single statement this allows much faster processing than doing one insert and looping your code to do the next insert. It removes the additional overhead of 99 of 100 rows. This generally will at least make things twice as fast as single row looping. Problem becomes if you get an error in one of the 100 rows. Then you have to loop that batch one at a time till you identify which row or rows that failed.

Comment: @Steve - essentially all database have some sort of bulk-load command, see [LOAD FILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) for MySQL.  It may not do `MERGE` natively, though - you may have to bulk-load to a temp table, slap an index on it, then tell it to shuffle into the real table.